# Hoopl: graph construction and automatic deletion of unreachable blocks

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, hoopl

I'm working on a project using the Hoopl library, and I've run into a snag that indicates to me that I don't fully understand what's going on under the hood. In a nutshell, Hoopl seems to consider some blocks in my graph unreachable that (IMO) it should not. I am implementing a sparse conditional constant propagation, so I do expect some blocks to *become* unreachable, but not all blocks! Below is an example taken from a HUnit test suite I'm using to prototype things. The example uses several functions that are not defined here, but I have separate unit tests for those confirming that they work in isolation, in particular, that `fromHoopl . toHoopl x` works as expected, and so on.

What I expect to happen is that `block_cprop_out` should be the result of running this pass, but the actual result is just the const-folded version of `block_cprop_in_0`: both the true and false branches are eliminated. The output from the HUnit test is below the code snippet.

To summarise what I'm doing at a high level, I create a closed/closed Hoopl Graph for each block, and then merge these graphs with `Hoopl.|*><*|`. I use a simple `Data.Map` to track the unique labels that Hoopl assigns for user labels, so that, when I rewrite a `Branch userlabel`, I can modify the Hoopl successor label to the correct Hoopl `Label`. However, it seems that Hoopl considers both the true and false branch blocks to be unreachable here, because after I run this forward analysis and rewrite, I get back a graph containing only the entry block.

`block_cprop_out` is a little weird here, because my `fromHoopl` function simply calls `Hoopl.foldGraphNodes` to turn the entire Hoopl `Graph a` into a simple `[a]` for inspection.

A separate test confirms that roundtripping this list of blocks using the same graph construction method (concatenating closed/closed blocks) works as expected; it seems that the elimination of unreachable blocks is triggered specifically by `Hoopl.analyzeAndRewrite{Fwd,Bwd}`.

Is splicing together a list of closed/closed blocks like I'm doing here correct? If so, can anyone see anything else suspicious here that might be causing Hoopl to believe that blocks are unreachable?

```
block_cprop_in_0 = [ --test for constprop
                     L $ Label "entry",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r0") (Reg "r0"),
                     T $ CondBranch (Reg "r0") (Label "tb") (Label "fb")
                   ]

block_cprop_in_1 = [ -- test for constprop
                     L $ Label "tb",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r1") (Reg "r0"),
                     T $ Halt
                   ] -- this block is unreachable from the CondBranch in block_cprop_in_0

block_cprop_in_2 = [ -- test for constprop
                     L $ Label "fb",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r2") (Reg "r0"), --should get rewritten as a SubI
                     T $ Halt
                   ]

block_cprop_out = [ --test for constprop
                    L $ Label "entry",
                    O $ Sub (Reg "r0") (Reg "r0"),
                    T $ Branch (Label "fb"),
                    L $ Label "fb",
                    O $ SubI 0 (Reg "r2"),
                    T $ Halt
                  ]

test_hoopl_6 =
  let p = [block_cprop_in_0, block_cprop_in_1, block_cprop_in_2]
      p' :: (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C) = H.runSimpleUniqueMonad $ H.runWithFuel H.infiniteFuel $ (transform p :: H.SimpleFuelMonad (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C))
      unP' :: [Instruction] = fromHoopl p'
  in unP' @?= block_cprop_out
  where
    transform :: (H.CheckpointMonad m, H.FuelMonad m, H.UniqueMonad m) => [[Instruction]] -> m (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C)
    transform prog = do
      (hlms, ps) <- liftM unzip $ forM prog toHoopl
      let hlm = Map.unions hlms
      let p = foldl (H.|*><*|) H.emptyClosedGraph ps
      let hooplLabelFor = fromJust . flip Map.lookup hlm
      let eLabel = hooplLabelFor $ Label "entry"
      let registers = ["r0", "r1", "r2", "r3"]
      p' <- runConstProp registers hooplLabelFor eLabel p
      return p'

    constLattice :: H.DataflowLattice ConstFact
    constLattice = H.DataflowLattice
     { H.fact_name = "Register Contents"
     , H.fact_bot  = Map.empty
     , H.fact_join = H.joinMaps (H.extendJoinDomain constFactAdd)
     }
     where
       constFactAdd _ (H.OldFact old) (H.NewFact new)
           = if new == old then (H.NoChange, H.PElem new)
             else               (H.SomeChange, H.Top)

    -- initially all registers have unknown contents
    initFact :: [Register] -> ConstFact
    initFact regs = Map.fromList $ [(r, H.Top) | r <- regs]

    -- transfer function: register value is a constant
    regIsConstant :: (Label -> H.Label) -> H.FwdTransfer (Node Instruction) ConstFact
    regIsConstant hooplLabelFor = H.mkFTransfer rc
     where
      rc :: Node Instruction e x -> ConstFact -> H.Fact x ConstFact
      rc (NodeInit _ _) f = f

      -- subtracting a register from itself yields zero
      rc (NodeCont (O (Sub (Reg a) (Reg b)))) f
        = if a == b then Map.insert a (H.PElem 0) f else f

      rc (NodeCont (O (Sub _ (Reg x)))) f   = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (SubI _ (Reg x)))) f  = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (SubM _ (Reg x)))) f  = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (Load _ (Reg x)))) f  = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (Store _ (Reg x)))) f = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (CmpEq _ (Reg x)))) f = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O (CmpLt _ (Reg x)))) f = Map.insert x H.Top f
      rc (NodeCont (O _)) f = f

      rc (NodeTerm (T Halt) _) f = H.mkFactBase constLattice []
      rc (NodeTerm (T (Branch l)) _) f = H.mapSingleton (hooplLabelFor l) f

      -- if we take the false branch of a CondBranch then the condition register contains zero
      rc (NodeTerm (T (CondBranch (Reg x) tl fl)) _) f
        = H.mkFactBase constLattice
               [(hooplLabelFor tl, f),
                (hooplLabelFor fl, Map.insert x (H.PElem 0) f)]

    -- rewrite function: replace use of reg with constant contents
    constProp :: forall m. H.FuelMonad m => (Label -> H.Label) -> H.FwdRewrite m (Node Instruction) ConstFact
    constProp hooplLabelFor = H.mkFRewrite cp
     where
       cp :: Node Instruction e x -> ConstFact -> m (Maybe (H.Graph (Node Instruction) e x))
       cp node f
         = return $ rw hooplLabelFor (lookup f) node

       rw :: (Label -> H.Label) -> (Register -> Maybe Integer) -> Node Instruction e x -> (Maybe (H.Graph (Node Instruction) e x))
       rw hooplLabelFor valueOf inst =
         case inst of
           -- if we see a subtract with constant, turn it into a SubI
           (NodeCont (O (Sub (Reg x) (Reg y)))) ->
             case (valueOf x, valueOf y) of
               (Just xi, _) -> Just $ H.mkMiddle $ NodeCont $ O $ SubI xi (Reg y)
               (_, Just yi) -> Just $ H.mkMiddle $ NodeCont $ O $ SubI yi (Reg x)
               _            -> Nothing

           -- if we see a CondBranch on a constant, turn it into a Branch
           (NodeTerm (T (CondBranch (Reg x) tl fl)) _) ->
             case (valueOf x) of
              (Just xi) ->
                if 0 == xi then
                  Just $ H.mkLast $ NodeTerm (T $ Branch fl) [hooplLabelFor fl]
                else
                  Just $ H.mkLast $ NodeTerm (T $ Branch tl) [hooplLabelFor tl]
              _ -> Nothing
           _ -> Nothing

       lookup :: ConstFact -> Register -> Maybe Integer
       lookup f x = case Map.lookup x f of
                      Just (H.PElem v) -> Just v
                      _                -> Nothing

    constPropPass :: H.FuelMonad m => (Label -> H.Label) -> H.FwdPass m (Node Instruction) ConstFact
    constPropPass hooplLabelFor = H.FwdPass
      { H.fp_lattice  = constLattice
      , H.fp_transfer = regIsConstant hooplLabelFor
      , H.fp_rewrite  = constProp hooplLabelFor
      }

    runConstProp :: (H.CheckpointMonad m, H.FuelMonad m) => [Register] -> (Label -> H.Label) -> H.Label -> (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C) -> m (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C)
    runConstProp registers hooplLabelFor entry graph = do
      (graph', _, _) <- H.analyzeAndRewriteFwd (constPropPass hooplLabelFor) (H.JustC [entry]) graph (H.mapSingleton entry $ initFact registers)
      return graph'
```

The HUnit output is:

```
hoopl_6: [Failed]
  expected: [L (Label "entry"),O (Sub (Reg "r0") (Reg "r0")),T (Branch (Label "fb")),L (Label "fb"),O (SubI 0 (Reg "r2")),T Halt]
  but got: [L (Label "entry"),O (Sub (Reg "r0") (Reg "r0")),T (Branch (Label "fb"))]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, If I simply comment out all the code inside the rewrite, the true and false branches are still eliminated, which is what leads me to believe there's something wrong with how I'm constructing the graph, as opposed to what I'm doing in the rewrite!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the issue was indeed not in this piece of code.

Rather than entering the label-mapping monad at the top level, I had placed separate invocations of runLabelMapM at the *leaves* of my transformation, which meant that I was accidentally allocating unique Hoopl labels to every user label in my program, as opposed to reusing Hoopl labels where the program reused user labels.

Of course, this meant that a `goto L3` and the matching `L3:` in subsequent code were being mapped to *distinct* Hoopl labels, rather than the same Hoopl label; the true and false branch blocks were absolutely unreachable, because to Hoopl they looked as though I had written this:

```
block_cprop_in_0 = [ --test for constprop
                     L $ Label "1",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r0") (Reg "r0"),
                     T $ CondBranch (Reg "r0") (Label "2") (Label "3")
                   ]

block_cprop_in_1 = [ -- test for constprop
                     L $ Label "4",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r1") (Reg "r0"),
                     T $ Halt
                   ] -- this block is unreachable from the CondBranch in block_cprop_in_0

block_cprop_in_2 = [ -- test for constprop
                     L $ Label "5",
                     O $ Sub (Reg "r2") (Reg "r0"), --should get rewritten as a SubI
                     T $ Halt
                   ]
```

Just a monad threading gotcha in the end!

For posterity, here is the correct code: I just needed to hoist `runHooplLabelMapM` outside of the `toHoopl` function to the top level.

```
test_hoopl_6 =
  let p = [block_cprop_in_0, block_cprop_in_1, block_cprop_in_2]
      p' :: (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C) = H.runSimpleUniqueMonad $ H.runWithFuel H.infiniteFuel $ ((transform p) :: H.SimpleFuelMonad (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C))
      unP' :: [Instruction] = fromHoopl p'
  in unP' @?= block_cprop_out
  where
    convert prog = do
      ps <- forM prog (toHoopl @[] @Instruction @Label)
      let p = foldl (H.|*><*|) H.emptyClosedGraph ps
      return p

    transform :: (H.CheckpointMonad m, H.FuelMonad m, H.UniqueMonad m) => [[Instruction]] -> m (H.Graph (Node Instruction) H.C H.C)
    transform p = do
      (hlm, prog) <- runHooplLabelMapM Map.empty $ convert p
      let registers = ["r0", "r1", "r2", "r3"]
      let hooplLabelFor = fromJust . flip Map.lookup hlm
      let eLabel = hooplLabelFor $ Label "entry"
      p' <- runConstProp registers hooplLabelFor eLabel prog
      return p'

...
```